# Search for key-value pair in string

Tags: java

I have a Java string with this content:

```
Response: Success
Message: Extension Status
Exten: 1234
Context: from-sip
Hint: DS/5678
Status: 9
```

I'd like to search this string for the keys `"Exten:"` and `"Status:"` and retrieve the corresponding values, i.e. `"1234"` and `"9"`. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: `String a="1234"; String b="9"`.... If that does not suit you, could you be more specific?

Comment: Where from you want to get value? Is it file? Please specify.

Comment: Updated my question. @Masud CSE CUET Input is a Java String variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a Regex to get them (`Pattern` class, with the `MULTILINE` flag flor simplicity):

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class RegexStrings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Response: Success\n"+
                        "Message: Extension Status\n"+
                        "Exten: 1234\n"+
                        "Context: from-sip\n"+
                        "Hint: DS/5678\n"+
                        "Status: 9";
        String exten = null;
        String status = null;

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^Exten: (.+?)$", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(input);
        if (m.find()) {
            exten = m.group(1);
        }
        Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("^Status: (.+?)$", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(input);
        if (m2.find()) {
            status = m2.group(1);
        }
        System.out.println("Exten: "+exten);
        System.out.println("Status: "+status);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exten: 1234
Status: 9
```

[**Online demo here.**](http://ideone.com/787Zu3)

---

If your string has a fixed format, you can use a combination of `String#substring()`, which may be easier to grasp:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Response: Success\n"+
                    "Message: Extension Status\n"+
                    "Exten: 1234\n"+
                    "Context: from-sip\n"+
                    "Hint: DS/5678\n"+
                    "Status: 9";

    String exten = input.substring(input.indexOf("Exten: ")+"Exten: ".length(), input.indexOf("Context: ")).trim();
    String status = input.substring(input.indexOf("Status: ")+"Status: ".length(),input.length()).trim();

    System.out.println("Exten: "+exten);
    System.out.println("Status: "+status);
}
```

(Same output)

[**Online demo for substring example here**](http://ideone.com/lzq53t).

Comment: This code is not scaleable in the sense that addition of a new key in input will require code change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.split() method with minimal usage of Regex.  Here is the code that is **generic** and converts given input into **Map for convenient programmatic access** to key-value pairs:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class NameValueCreator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "Response: Success\nMessage: Extension Status\nExten: 1234\nContext: from-sip\nHint: DS/5678\nStatus: 9";
        System.out.println(input);

        //Convert given input to Map
        Map<String, String> nameValuePairs = convertToMap(input);


        System.out.println("------------- converted map -----------------");
        System.out.println(nameValuePairs);

    }

    public static Map<String, String> convertToMap(String input) {
        Map<String, String> nameValuePairs = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        //Split by newline to split the input into lines, where each line represents one key value pair
        String[] nameValueStrings = input.split("\\n");
        for (String nameValueString : nameValueStrings) {
            //Split by colon followed by space
            String[] nameAndValue = nameValueString.split(": ");
            nameValuePairs.put(nameAndValue[0].trim(), nameAndValue[1].trim());
        }
        return nameValuePairs;
    }

}
```

Here is the output of the above program:

```
Response: Success
Message: Extension Status
Exten: 1234
Context: from-sip
Hint: DS/5678
Status: 9
------------- converted map -----------------
{Context=from-sip, Exten=1234, Hint=DS/5678, Message=Extension Status, Response=Success, Status=9}
```

**Not sure whether you really want to search with ":" being part of key such as `Exten:`, if so, then replace `nameValueString.split(": ");` with `nameValueString.split(" ");`**

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    String read = "Response: Success\n" +
            "Message: Extension Status\n" +
            "Exten: 1234\n" +
            "Context: from-sip\n" +
            "Hint: DS/5678\n" +
            "Status: 9";
    String[] arr;
    arr = read.split("\n");
    for (String i : arr) {
        if (i.contains("Exten:") || i.contains("Status:")) {
            System.out.println(i.split(" ")[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java properties class has inbuilt parser for such name value pairs terminated by new line. We can do something like this:

Properties p = properties.load ( new ByteArrayInputStream(xxx...);
 P.getProperty (your key);

This will make your code small and readable.